# Proof that a sequence subspace is perfect (or not)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, functional-analysis, proof-verification

Let $S = \prod_{k=1}^\infty \left\{0, \frac{1}{2^k} \right\} \subset (\ell_1, \|\cdot\|_1)$. I want to find out whether or not $S$ is perfect. I think that $S$ is perfect, and I seem to know how to prove that $S$ contains no isolated points, but I'm having trouble proving that $S$ is also closed.

> Part I. $S$ has no isolated points.

Suppose there is a sequence $x=(x_k)_k \in S$ such that $x$ is isolated in $\ell^1$. Then $\exists \varepsilon>0$ such that $B_\varepsilon\setminus \{x\}\cap S=\emptyset$. Let $\varepsilon>0$ and consider $y=(y_k)_k = \begin{cases} 
      0 & x_k= 0 \\
      \frac{1}{2^K} & \mbox{otherwise} 
   \end{cases},$

where $K\in\mathbb{N}$ is chosen such that $k\ge K\implies \frac{1}{2^k}<\frac{\varepsilon}{2(K-1)}$. Also, since $x, y\in \ell^1$, $\forall \varepsilon>0, \exists K' \in\mathbb{N}$ such that $k\ge K'\implies \sum_k|x_k-y_k|<\varepsilon/2$. Let $M:=\max\{K, K'\}$, then

$$\|x-y\|_1=\sum_k |x_k-y_k|=\sum_{k=1}^{M-1}|x_k-y_k|+\sum_{k=M}^\infty |x_k-y_k|<(K-1)\frac{\varepsilon}{2(K-1)}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}=\varepsilon.$$

Thus $S$ has no isolated points (by contradiction).

> Now, for the part with the closedness of $S$.

Suppose $S$ is not closed, then $\ell^1\setminus S$ is not open. Then there exists $p=(p_k)_k\in \ell^1\setminus S$ such that for every $\varepsilon >0$, $B_\varepsilon(p)\cap S\ne \emptyset\ne B_\varepsilon(p)\cap \ell^1\setminus S$...

That's where I'm stuck. I was entertaining the idea that there are sequences in both $S$ and $\ell^1\setminus S$ that converge to the constant sequence $\{0,\dots,0,\dots\}$. Is this right? Then it should be true that neither $S$ nor $\ell^1\setminus S$ is open. Then $S$ is not perfect.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: What does it mean that $S$ is perfect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make sure, $S$ is defined as:

$$S = \left\{(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty \in \ell^1 : x_n \in \left\{0, \frac{1}{2^n}\right\}, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$$

In your proof that $S$ has no isolated points, it seems that $y = x$, since you defined $y_n = 0$ if $x_n = 0$ and $y_n = \frac{1}{2^n}$ if $x_n \ne 0$, that is $x_n = \frac{1}{2^n}$.

To prove that $S$ has no isolated points take $x = (x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty} \in S$ and $\varepsilon > 0$. Let $k \in \mathbb{N}$ be such that $\frac{1}{2^k} < \varepsilon$. Define $y = (y_n)_{n=1}^\infty S$ as:

$$y_n = \begin{cases}
x_n,  & \text{if $n \ne k$} \\
\frac{1}{2^n} - x_n, & \text{if $n = k$}
\end{cases}$$

We have:

$$\|y - x\|_1 = |y_k - x_k| = \left|\frac{1}{2^k} - 2x_k\right| \le \frac{1}{2_k} < \varepsilon$$

So, $y \in \big(B(x, \varepsilon)\setminus \{x\}\big) \cap S$. Thus, $S$ has no isolated points so $S \subseteq S'$.

To prove that $S$ is closed notice that convergence in $\|\cdot\|_1$ implies pointwise convergence. Assume $x^{(n)} \xrightarrow{\|\cdot\|_1} x$, where $\left(x^{(n)}_k\right)_{k=1}^\infty$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $(x_k)_{k=1}^\infty$ are sequences in $\ell^1$:
$$\left|x_k - x^{(n)}_k\right| \le \left\|x - x^{(n)}\right\|_1 \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0, \quad \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$$

Now let $\left(x^{(n)}\right)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence in $S$ which converges to $x \in \ell^1$. By the above observation, $\left(x^{(n)}\right)_{n=1}^\infty$ must also converge pointwise to $x$. Since $x^{(n)}_k \in \left\{0, \frac{1}{2^k}\right\}$ every coordinate sequence $\left(x^{(n)}_k\right)_{n=1}^\infty$ must be eventually constant. Thus, $x_n \in \left\{0, \frac{1}{2^k}\right\}$ so $x \in S$.

Thus, $S$ is closed so $S' \subseteq S$. This gives $S' = S$ so $S$ is perfect.

---

$\left(x^{(n)}\right)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequence of vectors in $\ell^1$, where each vector $x^{(n)}$ is itself a sequence of complex numbers. I used the superscript rather than a subscript to avoid confusion with $x_n$ which usually represents the $n$-th coordinate of a sequence $x$. Anyway, for each of the vectors $x^{(n)}$ let's denote its $k$-th coordinate as $x^{(n)}_k$:

$$x^{(n)} = \left(x^{(n)}_1, x^{(n)}_2, x^{(n)}_3, \ldots\right) = \left(x^{(n)}_k\right)_{k=1}^\infty$$

Now, for a fixed $k \in \mathbb{N}$ you can consider the sequence $\left(x^{(1)}_k, x^{(2)}_k, x^{(3)}_k, \ldots\right) = \left(x^{(n)}_k\right)_{n=1}^\infty$, which is the sequence of $k$-th coordinates of sequences $x^{(n)}$, as $n$ varies. This is usually called a coordinate sequence.

Suppose that $x^{(n)} \xrightarrow{\|\cdot\|_1} x$, i.e. the sequence of vectors $\left(x^{(n)}\right)_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to a vector $x \in \ell^1$ in $\|\cdot\|_1$ norm. I showed that for a fixed $k \in \mathbb{N}$ we then also have that the coordinate sequence $\left(x^{(n)}_k\right)_{n=1}^\infty$ converges (as a sequence in $\mathbb{C}$) to the $k$-th coordinate of $x$, i.e. $x^{(n)}_k \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} x_k$.

In our example, since $x^{(n)}_k \in \left\{0, \frac{1}{2^k}\right\}$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, we must also have $x_k \in \left\{0, \frac{1}{2^k}\right\}$. This means that $x \in S$, so each limit of a convergent sequence in $S$ must also necessarily be in $S$.

Comment: Actually I defined $y_k = 0$ if $x_k = 0$ and $y_k=\frac{1}{2^K}$ (please note the capital $K$, where $k\le K$). I think it would be better to specify it as $K+1$ instead.

Also, can you please clarify why $x_n$ is eventually constant?

Comment: @sequence I see, my bad. It's not correct since you cannot bound $\sum_{k=1}^{M-1}|x_k-y_k|$ by $(K - 1)\cdot \frac{1}{2^K}$ because if $x_k = \frac{1}{2^k}$ then you have $|x_k-y_k| =  \frac{1}{2^k} - \frac{1}{2^K}$.

Comment: Sure, the coordinate sequence $\left(x^{(n)}_k\right)_{n=1}^\infty
$ is convergent for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and it has values only in $\left\{0, \frac{1}{2^k}\right\}$. It must also be Cauchy so if you choose for example $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{2^{k+1}}$, we get that $\|x^{(p)}_k - x^{(q)}_k\| < \frac{1}{2^{k+1}}$ for large $p, q \in \mathbb{N}$ so it must be constant.

Comment: Can you please clarify what exactly a "coordinate sequence" means and what exactly does it converge to? I mean what does the superscript $(n)$ mean? @mechanodroid

Comment: @sequence See the edit.